# Почему — "ушлый"?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

О хитром шустром человеке говорят, что он "ушлый". Еще могут сказать о мастере своего дела. А почему именно ушлый? При чем тут "уходить"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Словарь русских синонимов и сходных по смыслу выражений. под. ред. Н. Абрамова, М.: Русские словари, 1999.

> ***дошлый*** знаток; ловкий, хваткий, хитрый, продувной, оборотливый, пройдошливый, смышленый, ***ушлый***, эрудированный, изворотливый,

(Курсив мой - b-s)

Мне тоже кажется, что значения тут не противопоставляются, наоборот, во многом синонимичны.

Вот насчет сведения к "отвертится", "уйдёт от ответственности" - сомнительно. 
Скорее уж "уходит кого/что угодно".

Comment: История этого слова связана с кулачными боями и драками: сhttp://subscribe.ru/archive/job.education.metody.mysli.slova/200905/14130747.html Были  плясовые стили русского боя типа "ломаный", "буза" и т.п. при этом одним из критериев качественного выполнения боя считался "уход" ИЛИ УКЛОНЕНИЕ ОТ УДАРА, поэтому славяне называли мастеров,умеющих уклоняться от удара "ушлыми",позже вообще хитрых и уклончивых людей стали тоже называть "ушлыми". Со временем первоначальное значение и происхождение слово забылось, 
осталось лишь косвенное.

Answer (score 3):

По-моему, как раз в значении "уходить".
Ушлый – это изворотливый, хитрый, пронырливый, из любого дела может извлечь выгоду, своего не упустит, а от неприятностей, от ответа уйдёт - извернётся и выкрутится.
Мастер в своём деле - "дошлый" до всего сам дойдёт - ушлый  от опасности уйдёт. Где-то эти слова соприкасаются в значениях, но в изначальном смысле разные.